# What are the different tables present in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

What are the different tables present in MySQL, and which type of table is generated when we are creating a table in the following syntax: 
create table employee (eno int(2),ename varchar(10)) ?

One of my senior asked me, I am not able to find it out.

Comment: Somewhere I found that Earlier it was MyISAM but not sure for now (these days) in PHP 5.3 and 5.4 ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your PHP version.  PHP and MySQL are separate products that are versioned separately.  It might be that when you USED PHP 5.3 or 5.4 you happened to be also using a version of MySQL < 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with MySQL 5.5, InnoDB is the default storage engine.  Prior to that, it was My ISAM.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-default-se.html

If you do not further specify the type of storage engine you want, you will get the default for the version of MySQL you are running.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'storage_engine';
```

will return the current default storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic kind of question a beginr ask, all answers are right till now, for further knowledge read this artical of dev.mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html

Answer (score 0):

its myisam is default tabel engine where tables insert by this query
and

- MyISAM Startup Options
- The InnoDB Storage Engine
- The MERGE Storage Engine
- The MEMORY (HEAP) Storage Engine
- The BDB (BerkeleyDB) Storage Engine
- The EXAMPLE Storage Engine
- The FEDERATED Storage Engine
- The ARCHIVE Storage Engine
- The CSV Storage Engine
- The BLACKHOLE Storage Engine